# How do I open a file and manipulate it in VimScript without displaying it in a window?

Tags: file, vim

Is there a way I can open a file in VimL/VimScript and keep it hidden from the user? I am writing a [plugin](https://github.com/Kazark/vim-tabv) which is attempting to figure out exactly what it should do by looking for and potentially searching the content of certain files. Currently I am doing an `:sview` to open the file in a new window. After using `:global/.../y a` to search the file and read out the results of what I found, I `:close` the file. However, by this way of doing it there is a chance for a strange user experience of seeing a file you did not explicitly request to be opened flash open momentarily before you and then close again. My current approach does what I need, but I would like to find a less visually jarring way to do this.

How do I open a file in VimScript in a way that I can manipulate it (read-only) without showing it in a window?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another answer that allows you to use a buffer.

Vim is single threaded, and any vimscript you run will run completely without the GUI being refreshed in the middle. So the new window flashing before the user is not a problem - you'll be done with it before Vim has a chance to refresh the screen.

What the user **can** notice, is the layout change. `sview` opens the buffer in a new window, so Vim might resize the currently open windows. When you close the temporary window the other windows will be resized again - the the end result might not be the same as the original sizes.

The solution? don't create a new window. Load the temporary buffer to the current window with `:view`, do whatever you need to do with it, return to the original buffer with `:buffer`, and close the temporary buffer with `:bdelete`(unless you want to keep it loaded.

This, ofcourse, will pose a problem if the currently loaded buffer is changed. `:hide` to the rescue! `:hide {cmd}` will run `{cmd}` as if the current buffer is set to `hidden`. That means that any command that switches the window to another buffer will simply hide the current buffer, even if it has changes.

So - simply load the temp buffer with `:hide view`. You might also want to restore it with `:hide buffer`, just in case something goes wrong and you introduce changes in the temp buffer(which means you should also close it with `:bdelete!`).

Answer (score 7):

You can always use `readfile()` to read the file into a list and work on the list directly, without using a buffer.

Comment: I had seen that, but it seems to be suboptimal because you cannot use all the standard Vim file-manipulating power (I was trying to do a multiline-regex). Still, +1.

Comment: Are you sure you need all that power? I managed to do [something similar(use a regex on a list of strings) in my Yankitute plugin](https://github.com/someboddy/vim-yankitute/blob/master/autoload/yankitute.vim#L12-L27) and it worked just fine.

Comment: good point; the cases when I do need it are probably rare. My algorithms are in their infancy anyway and likely will change.